# How to convert dante.conf (socksify) to tsocks.conf?

Tags: socks

from dante.conf:

```
route {
    from: 0.0.0.0/0   to: 10.132.165.95/16   via: 127.0.0.1 port = 1084
    proxyprotocol: socks_v5
}
```

How can I convert these rules to work under tsocks?

Purpose: socksify on Ubuntu 11.04 always crashes because of lib errors.

Comment: Asking for an update: Did provided the answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like following

```
path {
    reaches = 10.132.165.95/255.255.0.0
    server = 127.0.0.1
    server_type = 5
    server_port = 1084
}
```